# How do I get a 100 hit combo?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In SSB4, there is a challenge where the game wants you to get a combo of 100. Is there any way to  get combo tht high?

Answer (score 3):

Use smart bombs in training mode. Get three close to the opponents, and throw the fourth on it. It can take multiple tries, but it is by far the easiest way to do it.

An example video:

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to smart bombs: you can set damage to 999%, grab your oponent, and mash the attack button.

It seems that not all characters can achieve the 100 hit mark that way; if you're struggling finding the right one, you can always try with Ness.

Comment: This is what I did, but with Samus. Much easier than smart bombs since it requires no complex preparation or retries.